# SED specific column replace

Tags: awk, sed

How to replace A to RA in column 4 using Sed command? (between these columns it contain more than one spaces)

```
ATOM     32  P     A     2       6.882  -5.338   6.560  1.00  0.00           P  
ATOM     33  OP1   A     2       7.505  -5.970   7.750  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     34  OP2   A     2       5.404  -5.201   6.610  1.00  0.00           O  
TER
```

can done by `awk '{gsub("A","RA",$4)}1' a.txt > b.txt`

Comment: you have answer already. do you have any problem with that?

Comment: I need to have spaces, awk command mess up spaces, thanks 
I think sed don't mess with spaces

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "spaces"? Are you talking about pretty-print tabular column formatting? Because if so, then adding `printf` to your `awk` command would take care of that.

Comment: yes, sed 's/A/RA/g' globe will replace every A in ATOM column too,  
in awk, it needs a long command like this,
awk '{gsub("A","RA",$4)}1' a.txt | awk '{if($1 == "TER"){print $0} else {printf("%-10s %d %10.3f\n",$1,$2,$7)}}' > b.txt
I noticed sed command can keep the same spaces as in the original file.
so I would like to have column specific selection with sed command. thanks

Comment: Why are the spaces important?

Comment: Tools don't mess up spaces, people mess up spaces :-).

Comment: this is a kind of file format call .pdb using for chemistry molecular dynamics and it may cause errors if the number of spaces changes sometimes.

Comment: In what way do you feel awk messes up spaces and what is it you need related to spaces in your output? For example should `A<blank><blank>` become `RA<blank><blank>` or `RA<blank>` or something else? ARE those blanks between fields or are they tabs or something else?

Comment: They are spaces, not tabs, and they do indeed appear to matter to [pdb](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html#ATOM)

Comment: But in what is it about them that matters? Is it the number of blanks between fields that matters or is it the width of the field including blanks and non-blanks, i.e. are the fields fixed-width with leading and/or trailing blanks around the text or are the numbers of blanks between fields fixed? Per that reference it looks like it's fixed-width-fields, not fixed numbers of blanks.

Comment: If you just need the columns to line up visually then `awk '{sub(/A/,"RA",$4)}1' | column -t` is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the spacing has to remain fixed, maybe that means the whole layout is fixed and then this may be what you're looking for using a sed that supports -E to enable EREs such as GNU sed or OSX/BSD sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{17})A /\1RA/' file
ATOM     32  P     RA    2       6.882  -5.338   6.560  1.00  0.00           P
ATOM     33  OP1   RA    2       7.505  -5.970   7.750  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     34  OP2   RA    2       5.404  -5.201   6.610  1.00  0.00           O
TER
```

or with any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\{17\}\)A /\1RA/' file
ATOM     32  P     RA    2       6.882  -5.338   6.560  1.00  0.00           P
ATOM     33  OP1   RA    2       7.505  -5.970   7.750  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     34  OP2   RA    2       5.404  -5.201   6.610  1.00  0.00           O
TER
```

---

EDIT: your input doesn't seem to conform to [the pdb standard](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html#ATOM) that @bushman posted earlier but if it did, here's how you can use the info from  the standard to create an array `f[]` of the fields by their tags/names, modify them by their tag/name (as opposed to their relative position in the input), and print them in the same fixed width format:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    # Record Format (copied from http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html#ATOM)
    #
    #                 COLUMNS        DATA  TYPE    FIELD        DEFINITION
    #                 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    flds[++numFlds]="  1 -  6        Record name   ATOM  "
    flds[++numFlds]="  7 - 11        Integer       serial       Atom  serial number."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 13 - 16        Atom          name         Atom name."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 17             Character     altLoc       Alternate location indicator."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 18 - 20        Residue name  resName      Residue name."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 22             Character     chainID      Chain identifier."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 23 - 26        Integer       resSeq       Residue sequence number."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 27             AChar         iCode        Code for insertion of residues."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 31 - 38        Real(8.3)     x            Orthogonal coordinates for X in Angstroms."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 39 - 46        Real(8.3)     y            Orthogonal coordinates for Y in Angstroms."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 47 - 54        Real(8.3)     z            Orthogonal coordinates for Z in Angstroms."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 55 - 60        Real(6.2)     occupancy    Occupancy."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 61 - 66        Real(6.2)     tempFactor   Temperature  factor."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 77 - 78        LString(2)    element      Element symbol, right-justified."
    flds[++numFlds]=" 79 - 80        LString(2)    charge       Charge  on the atom."

    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
        fld = flds[fldNr]

        cols = substr(fld,1,16)
        gsub(/ /,"",cols)
        n = split(cols,begEnd,/-/)

        tag  = substr(fld,31,13)
        gsub(/ /,"",tag)

        tags[fldNr] = tag
        begs[tag] = begEnd[1]
        wids[tag] = begEnd[n] - begEnd[1] + 1

        # Uncomment this if interested in the values the arrays contain:
        # print "<" fldNr "><" tags[fldNr] "><" begs[tag] "><" wids[tag] ">" | "cat>&2"
    }
}

{
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
        tag = tags[fldNr]
        f[tag] = substr($0,begs[tag],wids[tag])
        gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",f[tag])
    }
}

f["resName"] == "A" { f["resName"] = "RA" }     # this is where you can change a field by its tag/name

{
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
        tag = tags[fldNr]
        printf "%-*s", wids[tag], f[tag]
    }
    print ""
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ATOM  32   P    RA  2    6.882   -5.338  6.560   1.00  0.00  P
ATOM  33   OP1  RA  2    7.505   -5.970  7.750   1.00  0.00  O
ATOM  34   OP2  RA  2    5.404   -5.201  6.610   1.00  0.00  O
TER
```

Obviously that's overkill for what you're trying to do right now but it's a good general approach to keep in mind and solves the problem you may hit with any other approach discussed so far of empty fields before the field you're interested in.

Comment: @ Ed M. I'm a fan of how you approach and finally deconstruct a pbm with awk. In this particular case, why didn't you choose the `FIELDWIDTHS` pragma?

Comment: Rakesh thanks! Because FIELDWIDTHS would have been specific to GNU awk only and this is easy to do without it pluse FIELDWIDTHS would only have let me split the fields up on the input side, I still needed a way to control the width of each field for the output and the `wids[]` array let me do both.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed -E "s/^(([^ ]+ +){3})A  /\1RA /" file1
```

Walkthrough

From the start of the input line `^`

`([^ ] +)` means capture a group `(    )` as a continuous sequence of non-space characters `[^ ]+` followed by another continuous sequence of spaces `+`

Catch this group for for `{3}` repetitions, so the next characters are going to be in your fourth field

Group all three of those repetitions together by wrapping in `(  )`

If that "supergroup", which is now stored in `\1` is followed by `A` (thats A with 2 spaces) then replace it with `\1RA` (that's with only 1 trailing space so you have kept the character count the same)

Comment: This works thanks, can you explain this more?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to produce a pretty printed tabular output with the column substitution, the following addition to your `awk` command will achieve that:

```bsh
awk ' gsub("A","RA",$4){for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%-9s",$i)}print "" }' a.txt > b.txt
```

with the `cat b.txt` output looking like:

```
ATOM     32       P        RA       2        6.882    -5.338   6.560    1.00     0.00     P
ATOM     33       OP1      RA       2        7.505    -5.970   7.750    1.00     0.00     O
ATOM     34       OP2      RA       2        5.404    -5.201   6.610    1.00     0.00     O
```

If you are looking for a more specific spacing between each column, you will have to forgo the `printf` loop and assign individual spacing to each field.

---

If you are looking for a very quick `sed` alternative, you can always just do:

```bsh
sed 's/ A /RA/' a.txt > b.txt
```

but this will substitute every " A " in the file with "RA" not limited to the 4th column, as `sed` uses a different field splitting method than `awk` . Nevertheless, using the above `sed` command will give you `cat b.txt` that will look like the following:

```bsh
ATOM     32  P    RA    2       6.882  -5.338   6.560  1.00  0.00           P
ATOM     33  OP1  RA    2       7.505  -5.970   7.750  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     34  OP2  RA    2       5.404  -5.201   6.610  1.00  0.00           O
```

Answer (score 0):

Method-1: GNU sed w/o backreferences

```
$ sed -re '
     h
     s/\S+/\n&\n/4
     s/\nA\n/RA/;t
     g
 ' file
```

Method-2: GNU sed with backreferences.

```
 $ sed -re '
      s/^(\s*(\S+\s+){3})(A(\s|$))/\1R\3/
 ' file
```

Note that both the sed solutions can be made Posix compliant, but they will come at the cost of code clarity and might cause backslashitis.

Method-3: Perl using awk like fields BUT with a twist, this one stores both field values and separators.So the 4th field becomes 8th and with a zero indexed array it is 7.

```
$ perl -F'/(\S+)/' -lane '
     $F[7] =~ s/^A$/RA/;
     print @F;\
 ' file
```